# xarray rolling does not match pandas when using min_periods and reduce

Tags: python-xarray

I am applying a custom function on rolling windows with specific `min_periods`. The output of `pandas..rolling.apply` matches what I expect; however, the output of `xarray..rolling.reduce` doesn't seem to take `min_periods` into account.

**MWE:**

```
import numpy as np
import xarray

def custom(x, axis=0):
    return np.mean(x, axis)

d = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,3))
r = d.rolling(10, min_periods=5).apply(custom)
print(r.iloc[0:10,:])

xd = d.to_xarray().to_array()
r = xd.rolling(index=10, min_periods=5).reduce(custom)
print(r[:,0:10])
r = xd.rolling(index=10, min_periods=1).reduce(custom)
print(r[:,0:10])
```

**Output:**

```
          0         1         2
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       NaN       NaN
2       NaN       NaN       NaN
3       NaN       NaN       NaN
4  0.632168  0.523669  0.543643
5  0.558694  0.565781  0.481204
6  0.559343  0.541787  0.415490
7  0.613457  0.554888  0.398999
8  0.579552  0.496799  0.397681
9  0.562591  0.525096  0.416461
<xarray.DataArray (variable: 3, index: 10)>
array([[     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,
             nan,      nan, 0.562591],
       [     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,
             nan,      nan, 0.525096],
       [     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,
             nan,      nan, 0.416461]])
Coordinates:
  * index     (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  * variable  (variable) int64 0 1 2
<xarray.DataArray (variable: 3, index: 10)>
array([[     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,
             nan,      nan, 0.562591],
       [     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,
             nan,      nan, 0.525096],
       [     nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,      nan,
             nan,      nan, 0.416461]])
Coordinates:
  * index     (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  * variable  (variable) int64 0 1 2
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug — would you mind reporting it on the xarray github issue tracker? Thanks!

Comment: @shoyer thanks, I opened an issue on the github page.

Comment: In case it is helpful for anyone else, this is the related github issue: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3066